# Cannot find Ouath2 secret and key to connect my pipeline to bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to use aws code pipeline but with bitbucket rather than git.So I found the follwoing document:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/

After going through it when I clicked on a template they provided, I get to the section which asks for OuathKey and OuathSecret. So to get the Ouath key and OuathSecret I found the following document  to get an access token:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html#OAuthonBitbucketCloud-Step2.Requestarequesttokenfrom

However this does not talk about Oauth key and secret. I could not find the Oauth key and Oauth secret anywhere in bit bucket. So does access token is the same as Oauth2 Secret? if yes then what is Oauth2 key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, you can't use BitBucket with CodePipeline. The only supported Source actions are S3, CodeCommit, and Github. [Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html)

In order to use BitBucket with CodePipeline you could write some kind of hook to create an .zip archive of your code on every commit and upload to a versioned S3 bucket. Then set that S3 bucket as your source.